# Change value when item is approved

Tags: workflow, development, javascript, jquery

I have a `MySQL table` which contains the `name` and the `quantity` of a material.

*I access it from a Sharepoint page using `Javascript` and `JQUERY Ajax` (jsonp).*

The user adds a request to retrieve a certain quantity from the list. This is where the problem appears: in the approval workflow, if the request is approved, the quantity from the database must decrease.

**How can I access my table and decrease the quantity when a request is approved?**

Call a php script from the workflow maybe? How can I do that?

I mention that I cannot use Visual Studio. Only Javascript and Sharepoint Designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create web service using PHP, then call the web service from custom Approval workflow. It means you will need to create copy of the existing Approval workflow so that you can modify it and add step that uses the "Call HTTP Web Service" action.

Instructions on using the action can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2012/09/05/how-to-work-with-web-service-using-call-http-web-service-action.aspx).

On SP2010, you can use [this](https://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/) CodePlex project to include Web Service calls in SPD.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Can I use this action in 2010 workflows? I can't seem to find it in Sharepoint Designer actions

Comment: Updated answer for 2010.